# New-mailbox script, with zipcode and P.O. Box values added to mailbox user account. possible?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am using the following powershell code for creating new mailboxes in my organization.

```bsh
$users = Import-CSV C:\mailboxes.csv  
$users| foreach {

$Password = convertto-securestring $_.password -asplaintext -force 
new-mailbox -name $_.name -alias $_.alias -FirstName $_.Firstname -LastName $_.Lastname -userPrincipalName $_.userPrincipalName -PrimarySmtpAddress $_.PrimarySmtpAddress -Database $_.database -RetentionPolicy "b3a83dc4-e471-4d05-b357-25535aa027af" -OrganizationalUnit $_.OrganizationalUnit -Password $Password –ResetPasswordOnNextLogon:$false
}
```

Is there a way to insert a static text/value to this "zip code" and "po box" boxes, on the new active directory user, created along with this mailboxes?

for example , zip code should contain: "0101010101" and P.O Box should contain "000"

Your assistance is most appreciated

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `Set-ADUser` from the `ActiveDirectory` module. At the beginning of your script (before any loops), you can run the following if you have the module available to your current session.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

After your `New-Mailbox` command, you can add the `Set-ADUser` command:

```
Set-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($_.userprincipalname)'" -PostalCode "01010101" -POBox "000"
```

Sometimes AD replication can cause inconsistencies with multiple commands against AD objects. To get around that, you would typically use the `-Server` parameter to consistently target a domain controller that will see all of your read and write operations. The alternative (a slower one) is to run the AD user modifications after all of the mailboxes have been created and data has replicated to the AD Site you would be targeting.

Comment: still waiting on further assistance with this . please assist if possible

Answer (score 0):

AdminOfThings - Thanks for your reply.

So tell me,

Considering your last comment about the AD User modification conflict that i might occur,
i`m thinking some sort of "time delay" code might resolve such issues.

would it be logical to add something like "Start-Sleep" command to add a delay between
the "new-mailbox" and "Set-ADUser" commands as you suggested?

if so can you...write down how my script should like exactly, adding all things together please?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, it fails with an error Set-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Filter'.